# Change tmux status bar if process is running

Tags: terminal, process, configuration, tmux

I was wondering if it's possible to change text in the tmux status bar (or BASH shell prompt as an alternative) if a specific process is running. I would specifically like an indicator to appear if the `script` command is running (which logs commands for a terminal session).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060443/how-do-i-set-window-title-color-in-tmux-2-9a/56814607#56814607)

Outcome of following the post when `htop` is running in second window the indicator changes to red.
[image]

It shows how when an other window in tmux has activity the window section can change to show that activity.

Quick notes: To create a new widow in tmux <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> and to switch between windows <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd>